# What is the purpose of shared tenant media folder in SXA?

Tags: media-library, sxa

SXA creates two media folders for new tenant:

[image]

What is the purpose of shared folder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**sitecore/media library/Project/New tenant** - this is media folder created for your project. In this example your project is called "New tenant"

**sitecore/media library/Project/New tenant/shared** media folder an be used when you have more then one site in the tenant. While using it you can share media across all of the pages within that tenant.